# Playing youtube video using iframe in ionic 2 app

Tags: iframe, youtube, ionic2, access-control

In an Ionic 2 app, I am trying to embed one youtube video using iframe. The code looks like this:

```
<iframe width="320" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?autoplay=1&controls=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However when I navigate to the page I am getting this error. I can't find a good answer how to fix this.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'https://www.youtube.com' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Not sure how to fix this. Any help/lead would be appreciated.

BTW, I am developing/testing in chrome browser developer tool.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You better add this to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

Also make sure your android manifest has:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved `iframe` problem by editing two `html_sanitizer.js` files. You ca find them under `node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\security` and `node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\esm\src\security` folders.

Open them and search for this line `var BLOCK_ELEMENTS`, insert iframe tag name and save. Now it should work, at least it works for me.

Comment: Thanks @DroidX. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `enablejsapi=1` inside the source.