# Displaying Youtube within an Ionic 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to display Youtube videos within an Ionic 2 application, with the URLs pulled in from a JSON data feed.

Individual videos can be displayed when the Youtube url is set in the constructor on the detail page, but I need the detail page to display videos for each of the videos in the JSON feed.

Here is how an individual Youtube video is able to display in Ionic 2 within detail.ts and detail.html:

1

```
import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

2

```
videoUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, public navCtrl: NavController) {
this.videoUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/DuwXCFyo4-w')
}
```

3

```
<iframe width="100%" height="315" [src]="data.youtube" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

ios tweak

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*"/>
```

**What I need is some code tweaking in detail.ts to allow *any* Youtube url?**

Here is the Youtube displayed in a **Plunker** on the detail page
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ar2whVFCmBAbE7fxA3nf?p=preview

[image]

One solution I have seen is below, but can't seem to get it working:

```
transform(videoId: string): SafeResourceUrl {
return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId});
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059601/playing-youtube-video-using-iframe-in-ionic-2-app#39398934

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You shouldn't be using embedded youtube frames on your ionic app.

You must use the [Ionic Youtube Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/youtube-video-player/)

To install it, go to your Ionic project in the command line:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer.git
npm install --save @ionic-native/youtube-video-player
```

Basic Usage:

```
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player';

constructor(private youtube: YoutubeVideoPlayer) { }

this.youtube.openVideo('myvideoid');
```

Of course 'myvideoid' is your youtube video ID passed as a string.

Comment: How should this be displayed HTML wise with the iframe? <iframe width="100%" height="315" [src]="data.youtube"

Comment: this.youtube.openVideo('myvideoid'); this function dose nothing on emulator

Comment: the Ionic YouTube plugin doesn't provide any capabilities other than displaying a single video ... meaning, I need to write myself the playlist, and there's no event that can catch the "video is done" .... it's a great plugin but doesn't do much.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="videowrapper">
    <iframe [src]="updateVideoUrl(video_id)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
        width="640" height="550"
    ></iframe>
</div>
<button (click)="watch_on_youtube(video_id)" ion-button small color="danger">
    <ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon>
    Or Watch On Youtube
</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-video-single',
    templateUrl: 'video-single.html',
})
export class VideoSinglePage {

    video_id: any;

    constructor(
        public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        public youtube: YoutubeVideoPlayer
    ) {
        this.video_id = 'your_video_id';
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad VideoSinglePage');
    }

    updateVideoUrl(id: string) {
        // Appending an ID to a YouTube URL is safe.
        // Always make sure to construct SafeValue objects as
        // close as possible to the input data, so
        // that it's easier to check if the value is safe.
        let dangerousVideoUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?rel=0&showinfo=0';
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(dangerousVideoUrl);
    }

    watch_on_youtube( video_id ) {
        this.youtube.openVideo( video_id );
    }

}
```

CSS (For Responsive Video Embedding):

```
page-video-single {
    .videowrapper {
        float: none;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 25px;
        height: 0;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    .videowrapper iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```